# How to POST a JSON to a specific url using VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, web-services, json, post

I'm a newbie about web services in VB.NET. I'm making a desktop application that will talk to JIRA (http://www.atlassian.com/software/jira/). They provided a REST api that I decided to use. The first step is to login which they say that...

**"To log in to JIRA, you need to POST a username and password in JSON format..."**

**{"username" : "admin", "password" : "admin"}**

**to this url...**

**https://addressgoeshere** (we are using https)

Can someone provide me a sample code to do this so I can have a guide and a good start?

Answer (score 41):

Here is the code to post json effectively. The variable `res` is able to give you the responce to your query

remember to import

- System.Net
- System.IO
- System.text

by using

```
Imports
```

and then the import names

to bypass expired ssl certificate check this: http://blog.jameshiggs.com/2008/05/01/c-how-to-accept-an-invalid-ssl-certificate-programmatically/

```
Private Function SendRequest(uri As Uri, jsonDataBytes As Byte(), contentType As String, method As String) As String
  Dim response As String
  Dim request As WebRequest

  request = WebRequest.Create(uri)
  request.ContentLength = jsonDataBytes.Length
  request.ContentType = contentType
  request.Method = method

  Using requestStream = request.GetRequestStream
    requestStream.Write(jsonDataBytes, 0, jsonDataBytes.Length)
    requestStream.Close()

    Using responseStream = request.GetResponse.GetResponseStream
      Using reader As New StreamReader(responseStream)
        response = reader.ReadToEnd()
      End Using
    End Using
  End Using

  Return response
End Function
```

to use this function

```
Dim data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonSring)
Dim result_post = SendRequest(uri, data, "application/json", "POST")
```

--EDIT--

The linked page has expired by now. Here is a working archived copy:

https://web.archive.org/web/20110924191356/http://blog.jameshiggs.com/2008/05/01/c-how-to-accept-an-invalid-ssl-certificate-programmatically/

Comment: Hi! Thanks! I finally got it working! But I have one little problem. When I tried using https it gave a 


**"An unhandled exception of type 'System.Net.WebException' occured in System.dll


Additional information: The underlying connection was closed: An unexpected error occured on a send."**


How can I make it work using https?Thanks!

Comment: That's kinda weird. I keep on getting that error. When I access the url in google chrome or any other browser it asks for a certificate which I just click "proceed anyway". Do you think it has something to do with it?

Comment: yes certificates are the culprit.. there is a way to bypass that via code, updated my answer.

Comment: Use `HttpWebRequest` for HTTP specific capabilities like Accept headers.

Answer (score 1):

For 'The underlying connection was closed:' error include these 2 lines of code after the line `...WebRequest.Create(Url)` -it should work

`System.Net.ServicePointManager.UseNagleAlgorithm = False`
`System.Net.ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = False`