# PHP process posted json

Tags: php, json

I have a VB.net desktop app sending webrequest to a PHP web server via:

```
Dim result_post = SendRequest(New Uri(strURL), data, "application/json", "POST")
```

The data is encoded using the Newtonsoft json encoding process

I am having a problem on the PHP side retrieving the posted json.

```
$data = file_get_contents('php://input');
//$data = '[{"products_model":"2481-5-50","products_name":"2481-5-50 Desk, Maple with an extended d","products_description":"Desk, Maple with an extended description\rAnd this is line 2","products_quantity":112,"products_date_available":"2009-07-08T00:00:00","products_url":"","fc_products_id":0,"updated":"2012-04-15T00:00:00","products_price":1109.95,"ImageFile":"","products_tax_class_id":1,"products_weight":0.00}]';

$json = json_decode($data, true);
Foreach ($json as $i => $row) {
   //sql insert code goes here
}
```

If I put the json text in the php file, the sql insert code works.  When I use the file_get_contents version I get no errors but also no inserted data.

What am I missing?

Comment: What does `var_dump($data)` show?

Comment: The response that I see in result_post is the html for the login page, to which I have already submitted the user and password, gotten another webrowser.documentcompleted event, and posted the json.  This setup works correctly to retrieve json data from php pages.

Comment: My vb.net code is based on this post:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384534/how-to-post-a-json-to-a-specific-url-using-vb-net

Answer (score 1):

You can check to see if `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` contains the information you are looking for. If you have  `always_populate_raw_post_data` set to true in your ini settings, then the input stream may have already been read into this variable.

Comment: What do you get on var_dump of `$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA` or `$data`?  What do you get as var_dump of `$json`?

Comment: I don't get anything form var_dump when I post from the vb.net program - see comment above.