# Sending SMS using API

Tags: vb.net, api, http, sms

I contacted my SMS company and asked them about API to send SMS by programming language.
they send the following code, but i didn't know how to use it in my vb.net application:

**By this method can send message to one contact or multi contacts
Request:**

```
POST http://api.yamamah.com/SendSMS
Host: api.yamamah.com
Content-Type: application/json
Body:
{
"Username": "",
"Password": "",
"Tagname": "",
"RecepientNumber": "05xxxxxx;05xxxxxx",
"VariableList": "",
"ReplacementList": "",
"Message": "test",
"SendDateTime": 0,
"EnableDR": False
}
Response
Status Code: 200
Content-Length: 70
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Sun, 26 Jan 2014 10:59:40 GMT
Returned message
{
"InvalidMSISDN": null,
"MessageID": "1d7d8d99-2da4-478a-8391-6783f467f479",
"Status": 1,  
"StatusDescription": "Success"
}
```

Comment: Which part do you have problem with? This seems like a simple [Web Request](http://stackoverflow.com/a/4015346/2882256) with a json as body. Addtiionally: Ask your SMS provider for documentation or a simple example.

Comment: all of it, i can't convert this code to vb.net code!

Comment: It´s not code. It´s a [post](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POST_(HTTP)) request.

Comment: @AlexB. can you help me to translate that post to vb.net code?

Comment: Lookout for a tutorial. And check @Gulrez answer. If you then have a specific programming problem come and ask again.

Answer (score 0):

- Research how to consume a REST webservice in vb.net application.
- Your SMS company has shared the below details

  - URL of the webservice: http://api.yamamah.com/SendSMS
  - HTTPS method: POST
  - Content-Type: application/json
  - message body in JSON format.
- You can send the messages to multiple contacts as the Recepient Number is semicolon separated. ("RecepientNumber": "05xxxxxx;05xxxxxx",)

Answer (score 0):

**Do not use this provider API because it's not safe.** Based on your sample, I can coclude that they're not using SSL/TLS for API calls and your password can be **easily** stolen by anyone between your computer and their server. Ask their support for a safer way of communicating.

Or you can look at [our API](https://developer.wavecell.com) which is also HTTP REST API. You can study how to send HTTP requests with JSON payload from VB.NET [over here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384534/how-to-post-a-json-to-a-specific-url-using-vb-net).

Then it might be useful to follow our [tutorial on sending single sms.](https://developer.wavecell.com/v1/tutorials/api-send-sms-single)

And then check out [bulk sms API call](https://developer.wavecell.com/v1/sms-api/api-send-many-sms) and it's [compact form](https://developer.wavecell.com/v1/sms-api/api-send-many-sms-compact) to send many sms like that:

```
POST https://api.wavecell.com/sms/v1/{subAccountId}/many/compact
Host: api.wavecell.com
Content-Type: application/json
Body:
{
  "destinations": [
    "6598760000",
    "+659870001",
    "tel+659870002",
    "+33(509)758-000"
  ],
  "template": {
    "source": "BRAND",
    "text": "Your message for all clients"
  }
}
```