# 500 Internal Error when sending a POST request to Api

Tags: json, vb.net, post, httprequest

So my goal is to send a HttpRequest to api, it returns a 500 internal server error.
According to them, other companies are succesfully using this Api, so it should work in theory. I send the json example string I use to test if it works, they confirmed it is correct. So what could cause the Error?

```
    Public Function SendStringToHttpServer(dataString As String, uriString As String, credentials As NetworkCredential) As String
    Dim resultInfo As String
    Dim request As HttpWebRequest = CType(WebRequest.Create(uriString), HttpWebRequest)
    request.Credentials = credentials
    request.Timeout = 6000
    request.Method = "POST"

    Dim byteArray As Byte() = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(dataString)
    request.ContentType = "application/json"
    request.ContentLength = byteArray.Length

    Try
        Dim dataStream As Stream = request.GetRequestStream()
        dataStream.Write(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length)
        dataStream.Close()
        Dim response As HttpWebResponse = CType(request.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

        dataStream = response.GetResponseStream()

        Dim reader As New StreamReader(dataStream)
        Dim responseFromServer As String = reader.ReadToEnd()
        reader.Close()
        response.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception

        Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message)
    End Try
    Return "done"
End Function
```

Note: I saw there are some similiar threads, like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384534/how-to-post-a-json-to-a-specific-url-using-vb-net). But I use it exactly the same way, so it SHOULD work but doesn't -.-
(Beside the fact that i have strict on and therefore cast explicitly)

**EDIT:** About the authentification methods: This works definitly, since if I use wrong username or password in the credenitals I get a 403: authorized Error and not a 500.

Furthermore the read request works just fine. Read request is very similiar just a basic HttpRequest which only requires the url and credentials.

**EDIT 2:** So I read that it can be tied to HttpRequest automaticlly adding and "Expect:100-continue" to the header.I prevent this now

```
ServicePointManager.Expect100Continue = False
```

But it still gives a 500 Error.

Comment: So, this entity did not provide any other specification for accessing their Api. Some authentication method, some specific header, a token? Do they have an on-line manual, a note, that explains how a basic connection needs to be initialized? No requirements at all. Just *post a JSON formatted string and hope for the best*.

Comment: Well, while they have send a word document with it, there is nothing of interest written. it's 95% just about which attributes are optional/required.
And beside that you find only an explanation how url should look like and this:
"Read Requests: GET
Save Requests: POST
Date-Format is always yyyy-MM-dd"

Comment: Well the company behind this API definitely needs to give you better support. Capture the entire request using a web debugger like [Fiddler](https://www.telerik.com/fiddler), then send it to them and have them examine/try it. Right now they're the only ones who can do anything about this.

Comment: Are POST request you do in your web browser and app identical? A 500 could indicate that there is missing data, like a single - or something (talking from experience).