# Transcribe Audio file to text file using google cloud speech API in vb.net

Tags: vb.net, speech-recognition, speech-to-text, google-cloud-speech

I cannot figure out the Google Cloud speech API to transcribe a .wav file to a .txt file using vb.net.

The authentication is working:

```
AuthExplicit2("AudioTranscription", "C:\AudioTranscription\GoogleAuthentication\GoogleTranscriptionAuthentication.json")
```

I have tried finding code examples to use as a template but i just can't figure out the code.
Can anyone help me with this?

```
    Try
        Dim fileStream As FileStream = File.OpenRead("C:\AudioTranscription\Audio\dictation-partial.flac")
        'Dim memoryStream As MemoryStream = File.OpenWrite("C:\AudioTranscription\Audio\dictation-partial.flac")
        'Dim memoryStream As MemoryStream = New MemoryStream("C:\AudioTranscription\Audio\dictation-partial.txt")
        memoryStream.SetLength(fileStream.Length)
        fileStream.Read(memoryStream.GetBuffer(), 0, CInt(fileStream.Length))
        Dim BA_AudioFile As Byte() = memoryStream.GetBuffer()
        Dim _HWR_SpeechToText As HttpWebRequest = Nothing
        '_HWR_SpeechToText = CType(HttpWebRequest.Create("https://www.google.com/speech-api/v2/recognize?output=json&lang=en-us&key=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE"), HttpWebRequest)
        _HWR_SpeechToText.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials
        _HWR_SpeechToText.Method = "POST"
        _HWR_SpeechToText.ContentType = "audio/x-flac; rate=44100"
        _HWR_SpeechToText.ContentLength = BA_AudioFile.Length
        Dim stream As Stream = _HWR_SpeechToText.GetRequestStream()
        stream.Write(BA_AudioFile, 0, BA_AudioFile.Length)
        stream.Close()
        Dim HWR_Response As HttpWebResponse = CType(_HWR_SpeechToText.GetResponse(), HttpWebResponse)

        If HWR_Response.StatusCode = HttpStatusCode.OK Then
            Dim SR_Response As StreamReader = New StreamReader(HWR_Response.GetResponseStream())
            Console.WriteLine(SR_Response.ReadToEnd())
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString())
    End Try

    Console.ReadLine()
    imgAudioFile.Visible = True
```

Answer (score 0):

The code within the [public documentation](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/sync-recognize#top_of_page) requires either [client libraries](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-client-libraries) or making a [post request](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-protocol).
As you're using the post request, you should upload your audio file to [Cloud Storage](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/quickstart-console#top_of_page) to use the url within your request according to the documentation instead of using your local file.
Regarding your POST request, you could send the [JSON body](https://cloud.google.com/speech-to-text/docs/quickstart-protocol) on your post request based on  [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7384584).