# How can I pass a DTO to a Rest API in vb.net?

Tags: c#, json, vb.net, api

I have an API method in one application (written in c#) that expects a DTO object

```
        public IActionResult SaveProviderToOmitFromDto(RadiologyBillingProvidersToOmitDto dto)
        {
            mProvidersToOmitService.SaveFromDto(dto);
            return Ok();
        }
```

I need to pass the DTO object in an older vb.net application.
So far I have a sub to pass a URL and DTO:

```
        Public Shared Sub SaveProviderToOmit(ProviderToOmit As ProvidersToOmitDto)
            Dim Url = String.Format("{0}RadiologyBilling/SaveProviderToOmitFromDto", Settings.GetApiUrlStart)
            API.SaveProviderToOmitFromDto(Url, PatchMethod, ProviderToOmit)
        End Sub
```

and another method to "patch" the DTO

```
    Public Shared Sub SaveProviderToOmitFromDto(Url As String, Method As String, ProviderToOmit As ProvidersToOmitDto)
        Dim Provider = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(ProviderToOmit)
        Dim Request = GetRequest(Url, Method, Provider.Length)
        Request.GetResponse().Close()
    End Sub

    Private Shared Function GetRequest(Url As String, Method As String, ContentLength As Integer) As WebRequest
        Dim Request = WebRequest.Create(Url)
        Request.Method = Method
        Request.ContentLength = ContentLength
        Request.ContentType = "application/json"
        Return Request
    End Function
```

How do I pass the DTO object to the API?  I expected to need to serialize the object but how do I pass the object in the request?

Comment: Will this help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/7384584/14072498

Comment: Yes that helped.  Should I delete my question?

Comment: I did not find any question with an accepted answer. Is it OK by you that I create an answer with the link that helped you, then you accept my answer? I think that will help others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could not find any question with an accepted answer for this here on Stack Overflow, but this thread without accepted answer, solved OPs problem:

[How to POST a JSON to a specific url using VB.NET?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7384534/how-to-post-a-json-to-a-specific-url-using-vb-net/7384584#7384584)

```
Private Function SendRequest(uri As Uri, jsonDataBytes As Byte(), contentType
As String, method As String) As String
Dim response As String
Dim request As WebRequest

request = WebRequest.Create(uri)
request.ContentLength = jsonDataBytes.Length
request.ContentType = contentType
request.Method = method

Using requestStream = request.GetRequestStream
requestStream.Write(jsonDataBytes, 0, jsonDataBytes.Length)
requestStream.Close()

Using responseStream = request.GetResponse.GetResponseStream
Using reader As New StreamReader(responseStream)
response = reader.ReadToEnd()
End Using
End Using
End Using

Return response
End Function
```

To use this function

```
Dim data = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(jsonSring)
Dim result_post = SendRequest(uri, data, "application/json", "POST")
```